# Content View inside List Fragment

Tags: android

I have created a list view to populate under a tab using listfragment as shown below. But i need to also write code to Show content text as "No Files on this tab" when the list returns empty. Is there a way to do this?

```
if(recordList.size()>0){
recordList = db.getRecordData();
while (count <= recordList.size()) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(SUBJECT, recordList.get(index).getSubject());
    map.put(ADDRESS, recordList.get(index).getAddress());
    map.put(BUSINESS, recordList.get(index).getbusinessName());
    myList.add(map);
    count++;
    index++;
}

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), myList, R.layout.record_item, new String[] {SUBJECT, ADDRESS, BUSINESS }, new int[] { R.id.subject, R.id.address , R.id.business });
setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView listView = getListView();

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    ....
});
}
```

Comment: Check by `if(recordList.size()==0)` then show your text.

Comment: what would be the code under it?

Comment: You can show it as you want

Comment: In relative layout add text view and list view in center and change visibility of both with condition given by @Piyush.

Comment: @Harry Its not my question. You can comment for OP

Comment: Added this below code inside: if(recordList.size()==0), but not working
ListView listView = getListView();
     listView.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.empty));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setEmptyView function available in ListView.
Please refer to this for more info:

[Correct use of setEmtpyView in AdapterView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807253/correct-use-of-setemtpyview-in-adapterview)

Comment: I tried this:
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), myList, R.layout.record_item, new String[] {SUBJECT, ADDRESS, BUSINESS }, new int[] { R.id.subject, R.id.address , R.id.business });
setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView listView = getListView();

final EditText empty= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.empty);

 listView.setEmtpyView();

still it doesnt show